# When Spring boot project war deployed in tomcat 8 server not working for serving images

Tags: spring-boot, war, tomcat8

Web config for static resources

```
@Configuration 
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:///C:/test/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Project pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>test.</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jersey.version>2.7</jersey.version>
        <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies for GuavaCacheManager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies for Unit Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application configuration

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan

public class Application {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * Entry point for the application.
     *
     * @param args
     *            Command line arguments.
     * @throws Exception
     *             Thrown when an unexpected Exception is thrown from the
     *             application.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * Create a CacheManager implementation class to be used by Spring where
     * 
<code>@Cacheable</code> annotations are applied.
     *
     * @return A CacheManager instance.
     */
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        final GuavaCacheManager cacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager("greetings");

        return cacheManager;
    }

    /**
     * Supplies a PasswordEncoder instance to the Spring ApplicationContext. The
     * PasswordEncoder is used by the AuthenticationProvider to perform one-way
     * hash operations on passwords for credential comparison.
     *
     * @return A PasswordEncoder.
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        this.logger.info("passwordEncoder");
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient("127.0.0.1"), "test");
        return mongoTemplate;

    }

}
```

In eclipse if I start spring boot application, then application serving images for this url
 http://localhost:8080///////images//profile//APM1184//originalImage_7a7zke527_.jpeg

If I deploy war file of this project in local tomcat 8 and start. This URL is not working saying 404 not found.

I have posted my code. please correct me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Having hard coded resource locations and mongo hosts is going to make it hard for you to manage your application. I would recommend moving those values into a configuration file. At the same time I would recommend using relative or root directory locations for resources instead of having the `C:\` in the path as that won't work for deployments to Linux or other environments where the resource isn't on the `C:\`. My guess is that Tomcat isn't allowing the application to read from that external location due to some security constraints on the Tomcat installation.

I would recommend reading this Getting Started Guide on serving static content: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot